# Mod Rewrite Loses Query Parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

The following rewrite rules are being used .htaccess on a simple PHP site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ /test/index.php?m=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The following URLs work properly:

```
domain.com/test/index.php?m=profile
domain.com/test/profile
domain.com/test/profile/
```

However, additional query parameters are lost with the rewrite:

```
domain.com/test/index.php?m=profile&id=2000   ==> works
domain.com/test/profile?id=2000  ==> does not work
domain.com/test/profile?id=2000  ==> does not work
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ /test/index.php?m=$1 [L]
```

to include the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ /test/index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which tells apache to append the existing query string to the new one (`m=$1`).

Comment: @rb-sfs you should click on the "check mark" on the left so that your question is marked as answered